# Can we have multiple contexts, on different levels in component tree, in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can we have multiple contexts in different components?
Say I have Component A, Component B (parent of A) and a main component called app.
I have created a context in app, and I want to have some context in B. So, Is this the right approach?
Will it cause any performance issue?

Comment: Yes, you can. Which types of contexts are you talking about? Two of the same type of context? Two different types of context? Classic or modern-style contexts?

Comment: I am talking about different types of contexts.